Downloading word file as PDF from SharePoint using Graph api looses sensitivity-label
I have a word file in SharePoint Online document library, this file has Sensitivity label assigned to it. I am downloading this file using Graph SDK with query parameter 'format=pdf'. The file is successfully downloaded and saved as pdf, however, the sensitivity labels are lost.
Graph url: Graph url: https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/drives/b!blTHg...nEk/root:/test03/document.docx:/con...
I opened the same file in browser (Open in browser) and clicked on File --> Save as --> Download as PDF; this step retain the sensitivity labels.
Why is the file (with conversion from word to pdf) loosing its sensitivity-label when downloaded from Graph API?
Note:

I tried downloading directly using SharePoint URL and there too Label
information is lost. The sensitivity labels does not carry any
control mechanisms i.e., they are used for information
classification.

Further Information (22/07): Below is the document properties of a pdf file that was saved to disk as Download as pdf, it has the sensitivity-labels.

Below is pdf file that was downloaded through Graph api (format=pdf),  it is stripped of all the properties (labels),

Since sensitivity-labels are critical to how documents are classified/secured, i would assume that the conversion would retain those information.  Further, perhaps the 'Download as pdf' would use the same office-service while converting file.  Why this discrepancy?  Its a loss of critical information.

Your Link is unauthorised so I will see no sensitivity as I can't see the PDF contents. That also goes for Microsoft Server proprietary contents.
"code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
        "message": "Access token is empty.",

From APPLICATION HELP:

... if you share documents with another organization that uses different label names, each organization can apply and see their own label applied to the document.
Guest users won't see your labels in their apps.

So you would need to glue a label onto the PDF surface as opposed to embedded for MS in-house tracking.
However I would not bother as both can be easily redacted or removed if it offends the user, anyway.
Try writing "Top Secret" or any stamped "sensitivity" overprint, as a removable watermark.

Thanks.  My concern is the loss of critical meta information.  I have added additional details.

The sensitivity-labels are key-value pairs that are added to files as metadata properties, i don't see why they should be lost, but i guess this requires fix from Microsoft end.  It anyways works when conversion happens directly from browser.
